# LevelGenerator not optimal

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently for generating levels I am using a not so optimal solution which runs fine levels dont have any lag generating the problem is this is a LOT of code and as levels get bigger and bigger this code is going to become increasingly difficult to manage so I am looking for a better solution.

How can I better create my levels? Are they better systems? Bitarray? What is a better direction to go in!

```C#
#region Level Generator
    private void LevelCreator(int level){
        if (level == 1) {
            Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos2 = new Vector3 (-1, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos3 = new Vector3 (-2, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos4 = new Vector3 (-3, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos5 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos6 = new Vector3 (-5, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos7 = new Vector3 (-6, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos8 = new Vector3 (-7, 0, 0);
            Instantiate (startCube, pos, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos2, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos3, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos4, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos5, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos6, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos7, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (endCube, pos8, Quaternion.identity);
            player.transform.position = pos + Vector3.up;
        } else if (level == 2) {
            Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos2 = new Vector3 (0, 0, 1);
            Vector3 pos3 = new Vector3 (0, 0, 2);
            Vector3 pos4 = new Vector3 (-1, 0, 2);
            Vector3 pos5 = new Vector3 (-2, 0, 2);
            Vector3 pos6 = new Vector3 (-2, 0, 1);
            Vector3 pos7 = new Vector3 (-2, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos8 = new Vector3 (-3, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos9 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos10 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, 1);
            Vector3 pos11 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, 2);
            Vector3 pos12 = new Vector3 (-5, 0, 2);
            Instantiate (startCube, pos, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos2, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos3, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos4, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos5, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos6, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos7, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos8, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos9, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos10, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos11, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (endCube, pos12, Quaternion.identity);
            player.transform.position = pos + Vector3.up;
        } else if (level == 3) {
            Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos2 = new Vector3 (0, 0, 1);
            Vector3 pos3 = new Vector3 (0, 0, 2);
            Vector3 pos4 = new Vector3 (-1, 0, 2);
            Vector3 pos5 = new Vector3 (-1, 0, 3);
            Vector3 pos6 = new Vector3 (-1, 0, 4);
            Vector3 pos7 = new Vector3 (0, 0, 4);
            Vector3 pos8 = new Vector3 (1, 0, 4);
            Vector3 pos9 = new Vector3 (1, 0, 5);
            Vector3 pos10 = new Vector3 (1, 0, 6);
            Vector3 pos11 = new Vector3 (1, 0, 7);
            Vector3 pos12 = new Vector3 (0, 0, 7);
            Vector3 pos13 = new Vector3 (-1, 0, 7);
            Vector3 pos14 = new Vector3 (-2, 0, 7);
            Vector3 pos15 = new Vector3 (-3, 0, 7);
            Vector3 pos16 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, 7);
            Vector3 pos17 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, 6);
            Vector3 pos18 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, 5);
            Vector3 pos19 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, 4);
            Vector3 pos20 = new Vector3 (-3, 0, 4);
            Vector3 pos21 = new Vector3 (-2, 0, 4);
            Vector3 pos22 = new Vector3 (-2, 0, 3);
            Vector3 pos23 = new Vector3 (-2, 0, 2);
            Vector3 pos24 = new Vector3 (-2, 0, 1);
            Vector3 pos25 = new Vector3 (-2, 0, 0);
            Instantiate (startCube, pos, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos2, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos3, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos4, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos5, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos6, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos7, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos8, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos9, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos10, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos11, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos12, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos13, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos14, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos15, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos16, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos17, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos18, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos19, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos20, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos21, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos22, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos23, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos24, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (endCube, pos25, Quaternion.identity);
            player.transform.position = pos + Vector3.up;
        } else if (level == 4) {
            Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos2 = new Vector3 (-1, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos3 = new Vector3 (-2, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos4 = new Vector3 (-2, 0, -1);
            Vector3 pos5 = new Vector3 (-3, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos6 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos7 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, 1);
            Vector3 pos8 = new Vector3 (-5, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos9 = new Vector3 (-6, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos10 = new Vector3 (-7, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos11 = new Vector3 (-6, 0, 1);
            Vector3 pos12 = new Vector3 (-6, 0, 2);
            Vector3 pos13 = new Vector3 (-5, 0, 2);
            Vector3 pos14 = new Vector3 (-7, 0, 2);
            Instantiate (startCube, pos, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos2, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (permCube, pos3, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos4, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos5, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (permCube, pos6, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos7, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos8, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (permCube, pos9, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos10, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos11, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (permCube, pos12, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos13, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (endCube, pos14, Quaternion.identity);
            player.transform.position = pos + Vector3.up;
        } else if (level == 5) {
            Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos1 = new Vector3 (0, 0, 1);
            Vector3 pos2 = new Vector3 (-1, 0, 1);
            Vector3 pos3 = new Vector3 (-2, 0, 1);
            Vector3 pos4 = new Vector3 (-3, 0, 1);
            Vector3 pos5 = new Vector3 (-3, 0, 2);
            Vector3 pos6 = new Vector3 (-2, 0, 2);
            Vector3 pos7 = new Vector3 (-1, 0, 2);
            Vector3 pos8 = new Vector3 (0, 0, 2);
            Vector3 pos9 = new Vector3 (0, 0, 3);
            Vector3 pos10 = new Vector3 (0, 0, 4);
            Vector3 pos11 = new Vector3 (0, 0, 5);
            Vector3 pos12 = new Vector3 (0, 0, 6);
            Vector3 pos13 = new Vector3 (0, 0, 7);
            Vector3 pos14 = new Vector3 (0, 0, 8);
            Vector3 pos15 = new Vector3 (-1, 0, 8);
            Vector3 pos16 = new Vector3 (-1, 0, 7);
            Vector3 pos17 = new Vector3 (-1, 0, 6);
            Vector3 pos18 = new Vector3 (-1, 0, 5);
            Vector3 pos19 = new Vector3 (-1, 0, 4);
            Vector3 pos20 = new Vector3 (-2, 0, 4);
            Vector3 pos21 = new Vector3 (-3, 0, 4);
            Vector3 pos22 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, 4);
            Vector3 pos23 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, 5);
            Vector3 pos24 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, 6);
            Vector3 pos25 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, 7);
            Vector3 pos26 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, 8);
            Vector3 pos27 = new Vector3 (-3, 0, 8);
            Vector3 pos28 = new Vector3 (-3, 0, 7);
            Vector3 pos29 = new Vector3 (-5, 0, 8);
            Vector3 pos30 = new Vector3 (-5, 0, 7);
            Vector3 pos31 = new Vector3 (-5, 0, 6);
            Vector3 pos32 = new Vector3 (-5, 0, 5);
            Vector3 pos33 = new Vector3 (-5, 0, 4);
            Vector3 pos34 = new Vector3 (-5, 0, 3);
            Vector3 pos35 = new Vector3 (-5, 0, 2);
            Vector3 pos36 = new Vector3 (-5, 0, 1);
            Vector3 pos37 = new Vector3 (-5, 0, 0);

            Instantiate (startCube, pos, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos1, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos2, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos3, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos4, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos5, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos6, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos7, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos8, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos9, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos10, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos11, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos12, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos13, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos14, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos15, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos16, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos17, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos18, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos19, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos20, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos21, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos22, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos23, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos24, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos25, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos26, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos27, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos28, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos29, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos30, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos31, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos32, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos33, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos34, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos35, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos36, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (endCube, pos37, Quaternion.identity);
            player.transform.position = pos + Vector3.up;
        } else if (level == 6) {
            Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
            Vector3 pos2 = new Vector3 (1, 0, -1);
            Vector3 pos3 = new Vector3 (1, 0, -2);
            Vector3 pos4 = new Vector3 (0, 0, -2);
            Vector3 pos5 = new Vector3 (0, 0, -1);
            Vector3 pos6 = new Vector3 (0, 0, -3);
            Vector3 pos7 = new Vector3 (0, 0, -4);
            Vector3 pos8 = new Vector3 (0, 0, -5);
            Vector3 pos9 = new Vector3 (0, 0, -6);
            Vector3 pos10 = new Vector3 (1, 0, -5);
            Vector3 pos11 = new Vector3 (1, 0, -6);
            Vector3 pos12 = new Vector3 (-1, 0, -6);
            Vector3 pos13 = new Vector3 (-2, 0, -6);
            Vector3 pos14 = new Vector3 (-3, 0, -6);
            Vector3 pos15 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, -6);
            Vector3 pos16 = new Vector3 (-3, 0, -5);
            Vector3 pos17 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, -5);
            Vector3 pos18 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, -4);
            Vector3 pos19 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, -3);
            Vector3 pos20 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, -2);
            Vector3 pos21 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, -1);
            Vector3 pos22 = new Vector3 (-3, 0, -1);
            Vector3 pos23 = new Vector3 (-3, 0, -2);
            Vector3 pos24 = new Vector3 (-2, 0, -2);
            Vector3 pos25 = new Vector3 (-1, 0, -2);
            Vector3 pos26 = new Vector3 (-4, 0, 0);
            Instantiate (startCube, pos, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (permCube, pos2, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (permCube, pos3, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (permCube, pos4, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (permCube, pos5, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos6, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos7, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (permCube, pos8, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (permCube, pos9, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (permCube, pos10, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (permCube, pos11, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos12, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos13, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (permCube, pos14, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (permCube, pos15, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (permCube, pos16, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (permCube, pos17, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos18, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos19, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (permCube, pos20, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (permCube, pos21, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (permCube, pos22, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (permCube, pos23, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos24, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (fallCube, pos25, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (endCube, pos26, Quaternion.identity);
            player.transform.position = pos + Vector3.up;
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: Have you considered of using `Array` or `List`? This way, you do not need to generate a new line of code for every new position you create - but simply need to add the element in the `Array` or `List`

Comment: not sure how I would implement them Ive thought about using a list to loop through the levels but coding it up I realized it was making more code then the if/else statements

Comment: Read your levels through external files such as XML files, and make your own level designer that can read and write the level files, or you can manually do it yourself in code :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Learn](http://www.dotnetperls.com/int-array) to use array. I suggest you go with `array` rather than `List` or other generics because of performance reasons. Since you know the size of vector needed for each level, array is the solution here. Went ahead to do this myself. The lines of code went from **262** lines to **128**. Reduced it to more than **half** the original size. Simply call `intializeLevels()` in the `Start()` function(once), now you can use `LevelCreator` function  anytime. Also learn about Object pooling because there is too much instantiation going on in your code.

```
Vector3[] level1ArrayPos, level2ArrayPos, level3ArrayPos, level4ArrayPos, level5ArrayPos, level6ArrayPos;

    //Initialize arrays. CALL ONLY ONCE in the start function. 
    void intializeLevels()
    {
        level1ArrayPos = new Vector3[8] { new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(-1, 0, 0),new Vector3(-2, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(-3, 0, 0),new Vector3(-4, 0, 0),new Vector3(-5, 0, 0),new Vector3(-6, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(-7, 0, 0)};

        level2ArrayPos = new Vector3[12] { new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(0, 0, 2),
            new Vector3(-1, 0, 2),new Vector3(-2, 0, 2),new Vector3(-2, 0, 1),new Vector3(-2, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(-3, 0, 0),new Vector3(-4, 0, 0),new Vector3(-4, 0, 1),
            new Vector3(-4, 0, 2),new Vector3(-5, 0, 2)};

        level3ArrayPos = new Vector3[25] { new Vector3(0, 0, 0) ,new Vector3(0, 0, 1),new Vector3(0, 0, 2),
               new Vector3(-1, 0, 2), new Vector3(-1, 0, 3),new Vector3(-1, 0, 4),new Vector3(0, 0, 4),
               new Vector3(1, 0, 4),new Vector3(1, 0, 5),new Vector3(1, 0, 6),new Vector3(1, 0, 7),
               new Vector3(0, 0, 7),new Vector3(-1, 0, 7),new Vector3(-2, 0, 7),new Vector3(-3, 0, 7),
               new Vector3(-4, 0, 7),new Vector3(-4, 0, 6),new Vector3(-4, 0, 5),new Vector3(-4, 0, 4),
               new Vector3(-3, 0, 4),new Vector3(-2, 0, 4),new Vector3(-2, 0, 3),new Vector3(-2, 0, 2),
               new Vector3(-2, 0, 1),new Vector3(-2, 0, 0)
            };

        level4ArrayPos = new Vector3[14] {new Vector3(0, 0, 0),new Vector3(-1, 0, 0),new Vector3(-2, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(-2, 0, -1),new Vector3(-3, 0, 0),new Vector3(-4, 0, 0),new Vector3(-4, 0, 1),
            new Vector3(-5, 0, 0),new Vector3(-6, 0, 0),new Vector3(-7, 0, 0),new Vector3(-6, 0, 1),
            new Vector3(-6, 0, 2),new Vector3(-5, 0, 2), new Vector3(-7, 0, 2)};
        Instantiate(startCube, level4ArrayPos[0], Quaternion.identity);

        level5ArrayPos = new Vector3[38] {
            new Vector3(0, 0, 0),new Vector3(0, 0, 1),new Vector3(-1, 0, 1),new Vector3(-2, 0, 1),
            new Vector3(-3, 0, 1),new Vector3(-3, 0, 2),new Vector3(-2, 0, 2),new Vector3(-1, 0, 2),new Vector3(0, 0, 2),new Vector3(0, 0, 3),
            new Vector3(0, 0, 4),new Vector3(0, 0, 5),new Vector3(0, 0, 6),new Vector3(0, 0, 7),new Vector3(0, 0, 8),new Vector3(-1, 0, 8),
            new Vector3(-1, 0, 7),new Vector3(-1, 0, 6),new Vector3(-1, 0, 5),new Vector3(-1, 0, 4),new Vector3(-2, 0, 4),new Vector3(-3, 0, 4),
            new Vector3(-4, 0, 4),new Vector3(-4, 0, 5),new Vector3(-4, 0, 6),new Vector3(-4, 0, 7),new Vector3(-4, 0, 8),new Vector3(-3, 0, 8),
            new Vector3(-3, 0, 7),new Vector3(-5, 0, 8),new Vector3(-5, 0, 7),new Vector3(-5, 0, 6),new Vector3(-5, 0, 5),new Vector3(-5, 0, 4),
            new Vector3(-5, 0, 3),new Vector3(-5, 0, 2),new Vector3(-5, 0, 1),new Vector3(-5, 0, 0)};

        level6ArrayPos = new Vector3[26] {
            new Vector3(0, 0, 0),new Vector3(1, 0, -1),new Vector3(1, 0, -2),new Vector3(0, 0, -2),new Vector3(0, 0, -1),
            new Vector3(0, 0, -3),new Vector3(0, 0, -4),new Vector3(0, 0, -5),new Vector3(0, 0, -6),new Vector3(1, 0, -5),
            new Vector3(1, 0, -6),new Vector3(-1, 0, -6),new Vector3(-2, 0, -6),new Vector3(-3, 0, -6),new Vector3(-4, 0, -6),
            new Vector3(-3, 0, -5),new Vector3(-4, 0, -5),new Vector3(-4, 0, -4),new Vector3(-4, 0, -3),new Vector3(-4, 0, -2),
            new Vector3(-4, 0, -1),new Vector3(-3, 0, -1),new Vector3(-3, 0, -2),new Vector3(-2, 0, -2),new Vector3(-1, 0, -2),
            new Vector3(-4, 0, 0) };
    }

    private void LevelCreator(int level)
    {
        if (level == 1)
        {
            Instantiate(startCube, level1ArrayPos[0], Quaternion.identity);

            for (int i = 1; i < level1ArrayPos.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                Instantiate(fallCube, level1ArrayPos[i], Quaternion.identity);
            }
            Instantiate(endCube, level1ArrayPos[7], Quaternion.identity);
            player.transform.position = level1ArrayPos[0] + Vector3.up;
        }
        else if (level == 2)
        {
            Instantiate(startCube, level2ArrayPos[0], Quaternion.identity);

            for (int i = 1; i < level2ArrayPos.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                Instantiate(fallCube, level2ArrayPos[i], Quaternion.identity);
            }

            Instantiate(endCube, level2ArrayPos[11], Quaternion.identity);
            player.transform.position = level2ArrayPos[0] + Vector3.up;
        }
        else if (level == 3)
        {
            Instantiate(startCube, level3ArrayPos[0], Quaternion.identity);
            for (int i = 1; i < level3ArrayPos.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                Instantiate(fallCube, level3ArrayPos[i], Quaternion.identity);
            }
            Instantiate(endCube, level3ArrayPos[24], Quaternion.identity);
            player.transform.position = level3ArrayPos[0] + Vector3.up;
        }
        else if (level == 4)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < level4ArrayPos.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 7 || i == 9 || i == 10 || i == 12)
                {
                    Instantiate(fallCube, level4ArrayPos[i], Quaternion.identity);
                }
                else if (i == 2 || i == 5 || i == 8 || i == 11)
                {
                    Instantiate(permCube, level4ArrayPos[i], Quaternion.identity);
                }
            }
            Instantiate(endCube, level4ArrayPos[13], Quaternion.identity);
            player.transform.position = level4ArrayPos[0] + Vector3.up;
        }
        else if (level == 5)
        {
            Instantiate(startCube, level5ArrayPos[0], Quaternion.identity);

            for (int i = 1; i < level5ArrayPos.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                Instantiate(fallCube, level5ArrayPos[i], Quaternion.identity);
            }

            Instantiate(endCube, level5ArrayPos[37], Quaternion.identity);
            player.transform.position = level5ArrayPos[0] + Vector3.up;
        }
        else if (level == 6)
        {
            Instantiate(startCube, level6ArrayPos[0], Quaternion.identity);
            for (int i = 1; i < level6ArrayPos.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if ((i >= 1 && i <= 4) || (i >= 7 && i <= 10) || (i >= 13 && i <= 16) || (i >= 19 && i <= 22))
                {
                    Instantiate(permCube, level6ArrayPos[i], Quaternion.identity);
                }
                else if ((i >= 5 && i <= 6) || (i >= 11 && i <= 12) || (i >= 17 && i <= 18) || (i >= 23 && i <= 24))
                {
                    Instantiate(fallCube, level6ArrayPos[i], Quaternion.identity);
                }
            }
            Instantiate(endCube, level6ArrayPos[25], Quaternion.identity);
            player.transform.position = level6ArrayPos[0] + Vector3.up;
        }
    }
```

Comment: very nice indeed I wanna leave this open for a few more days see if anybody has some other suggestions but afterwards I will accept your answer :)

Comment: @JoséphFlames That's fine. There is always room for improvement. Your code would have been shorter if you made endCube,fallCube,startCube,permCube into arrays. Then you can use for loops for those. Anyways, the more you optimize,readability will go down. Happy Coding!

Comment: would you mind upvoting the question so i can set bounties :)

Comment: @JoséphFlames Just saw your comment and will upvote. The only way to make your code better without making it unreadable is to use xml or json. I would suggest you go with json. Unity has built in API to serialize and read a json file.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest for you to have a class to translate level files. You would have to make a function that would read all the levels and configure them. As far as i see they have a pattern of properties so it would be easier. This might take a little while but comes in handy with the introduction of more and bigger levels in your game.

The other benefits of doing so is that you could use a txt, xml, xls, json or other file that would make the work of editing and creating new levels easier and organized, and not doing it inside the core code.

Apart from that you could also easily make the reverse behaviour of that read function to write levels to file, which would make possible to save levels, to export levels you make in the Unity editor to store them.

I've made this in one of my games and i can assure you that it wouldn't take more than 15 lines of code to do the reading, another 10 to do the writing, and the files depending on the levels. But the greatest point of this is really the possibility to scale your game content.

Example using Json file:

```
{
  "level": 6,
  "cubes": [
    {
      "type": 0,
      "posx": 2,
      "posy": 1,
      "posz": 5
    },
    {
      "type": 1,
      "posx": 5,
      "posy": 4,
      "posz": 8
    },
    {
      "type": 2,
      "posx": 8,
      "posy": 1,
      "posz": 2
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "posx": 2,
      "posy": 2,
      "posz": 2
    },
    {
      "type": 3,
      "posx": 2,
      "posy": 3,
      "posz": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Then with a help of a class **Level** and **Cube** (the Type field to know if it is a fallCube,endCube,startCube)

```
public class Level
{
    public int LevelIndex{ get; set; }
    public Cube[] Cubes { get; set; }

    public Level(int level)
    {
        LevelIndex = level;
    }
    //method to add Cube to the array of Cubes
}

public class Cube
    {
        public int Type { get; set; }
        public int positionx { get; set; }
        public int positiony { get; set; }
        public int positionz { get; set; }

        public Cube(int type,int x,int y,int z)
        {
            Type = type;
            positionx = x;
            positiony = y;
            positionz = z;
        }
 }
```

And for each level file .json you would use something like:

```
Level newlevel = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Level>(jsonfile);
```

And to write :

```
String savedleveljson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(leveltowrite);
```

Comment: hmmm maybe provide some good code examples and i believe this would be an answer worth the bounty

Comment: I provided good examples for the case of json file. I did answer the questions and supported it now with code samples. In case you wish to get more detail is best for you to contact me. hope you upvote n rep.